# Suitescript Loading item records from Multiple Select Field

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

What I have is a multiple select field that has a list of items that our customers' use.  Some of our customers are using different hardware under the same category. I have a field in the Customer page which is a multiple select field and I am trying to take that information and insert into the case form with the beforeSubmit function.  Since I'm pulling an item, when I pull the field for item, it gives the internal id rather than name.  So I've also referred back to item list to get me an Item name rather than Item internal id.

The problem I am having is that i can't figure out how to best split the internal id's up and load the records to pull the information. Right now it looks something like this.

`var company = nlapiGetFieldValue('company');
  var custRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', company); 
  var CustomerTerminal = custRecord.getFieldValue('custentity89');  //ItemInternal Id

  var termItemRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('inventoryitem',CustomerTerminal); 
  var termItemName = termItemRecord.getFieldValue('itemid');
  nlapiSetFieldValue('custevent129',termItemName);`

This returns 5615 2063 3578.

After this I don't know how to proceed since it's three products. I just started coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe split that into an array with the `.split(" ")` operation. Then loop through and do something with each value. Are there values supposed to help populate another multi-select on the case form?

Comment: I created a free form text field in the case form, but ultimately i need each item to be loaded and pull the entity id rather than internal id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiselect fields, you will want to use `nlapiGetFieldValues` (note the *plural*). This should return you an Array of the selected IDs as Strings.

If you continue using `nlapiGetFieldValue` (singular), I believe you'll find that you'll have to split on `\x05` instead of the space character. May try copying and pasting the return value into a program like Notepad++ and then displaying hidden/special characters to be sure. I believe I have seen this on several past occasions, though it could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get field value in  particular customer ?? to get some Values Try to use `nlapiLookupField(type, id, fields, text);` **nlapiloadrec**  will take more unit

Comment: Alright i'll give this a shot, Thank you! On the Customer page we created fields to pull our service equipment from the item list and now we need to replicate that information every time a case is created.